# zipkin distributed tracing demo

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin, distributed-tracing

I am new to distributed tracing and trying to use the example explained in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFLZJSwbYI0

In short this has following

1. Zipkin server - for this I am using jar file provided by
   https://zipkin.io/pages/quickstart.html
2. one zipkin client (port - 8081)
3. service (port - 8082)

Now when I run zipkin server using command

> java -jar zipkin.jar

and accesing zipkin at url
    http://localhost:9411/zipkin

---

So far everything works fine.

Now I am starting zipkin-client/service which is running at port 8081/8082

After this i accessed zipkin url (http://localhost:9411/zipkin) but it's broken now.

I am wondering why starting other service on port 8081/8081 is causing zipkin server to stop responding.

Any kind of help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Its strange but I am able to access the zipkin url when I cleared the cahce of browser!!

Comment: can you please add some logs when your zipkin server is broken?